# How to present a view exactly like this?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, modalviewcontroller

How to present a view controller exactly like this. I mean the passcode view in the front.

I know how to create the view but not how to present it.

[image]

Comment: Screenshot? Otherwise you're limiting your answerers to people who have those apps installed on an iPad and can be bothered to go and look.

Comment: I added screenshot. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented such a screen using a `UIPopoverController`. Something like this:

```
UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:content];
UIView *root = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
CGRect frame = root.frame;
frame.origin = CGRectCenter(frame);
frame.size = CGSizeMake(1, 1);

[popover presentPopoverFromRect:frame inView:root permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
```

The frame is a center point of the screen. Passing 0 for the arrow directions prevents the usual arrow from appearing on the popover. `content` is the view controller you wish to display.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation is basically a `viewController` with appropriate methods. But you need not so everything. no need to re-invent the wheel. It as there are some pretty nifty 3rd party libraries to do this. Check out -

- [PassViewController](https://github.com/lashad/PTPasscodeViewController)
- [PinView](https://github.com/guicocoa/pinview)

Hope this helps...

Comment: I wanted to know the way the passcode view is being presented. In both the examples you gave, it was being presented modally which is not what exactly I am looking for. Thanks for your response. And I edited the question to be specific.